# It there any analog of level-list for colors on Android?

Tags: android, skinning

I am trying to find a way to give a user the possibility to switch between different color schemes (that includes different colors and images). All schemes are predifined, i.e. compiled and located inside the app. As I can see, for drawables I can do this by using level-list where each level corresponds to one scheme. But what about colors? Is there any way to do the same for colors? Or maybe there is a better way to implement color schemes switching?

Comment: Levels are not intended for this at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ColorStateList](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) which you can retrieve with `getResources().getColorStateList(id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in [mechanism](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) of styles and themes.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? Because I can't see the way to dynamicaly change styles, moreover there is no way apply styles to existing components from code - some components can accept style as a constructor parameter, but I don't want to loose the flexibility of defining components in xml.

Comment: Check this link for a sample: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html